# What should I use in Drupal 8 instead of votingapi_set_vote()?

Tags: 8

VotingAPI [docs](https://github.com/malcomio/votingapi/blob/migrate/API.txt) are out of date. `votingapi_set_vote()` has been removed in Drupal 8.

What should I use in its place to programmatically set votes (for instance in a migration)?

Comment: For D8 It is not defined anywhere. In D7 it was defined in the .module file. Thus, looks like they have not updated their docs & code comments on D8.

Comment: it's also called in votingapi.drush.inc and reference throughout drupal 8 docs as well; @kiamlaluno, fast & accurate responses are often the most helpful and having this answer indexed would probably help many 30+ minutes going down the wrong direction. nevertheless, question updated.

Comment: @NoSssweat, are you familiar with the votingapi for D8? Do you know how to set votes programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know how to set votes programmatically?

```
use Drupal\votingapi\Entity\Vote;

$vote = Vote::create(['type' => 'vote']); // this comes from /admin/structure/vote-types
$vote->setVotedEntityType('node'); // entity type
$vote->setVotedEntityId($nid); // node id
$vote->setValueType('points'); // this comes from /admin/structure/vote-types
$vote->setValue(1); // the number of points given per vote
$vote->setOwnerId($uid); // the user id of the person who casted the vote
$vote->setCreatedTime($timestamp) // timestamp of when vote was casted (optional)
// it will use the current time if you don't include it
$vote->save();
```

The above code will create 1 casted vote. Therefore, you will have to run this code for every single vote.

Comment: How do you get the vote results for a single node?

Comment: // Get rating from votingapi.
      $voting_service = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.votingapi.resultfunction');
      $results = $voting_service->getResults('node', $node->id());

Comment: https://makedrupaleasy.com/articles/drupal-8-how-get-your-star-ratings-google-search-results